# Can't Reference DLL's from mapped network drive in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, dll, reference

So I have a couple of projects that use referenced DLL's and recently we made a Network(X:) Drive which will always contain the latest DLL's.

Now I have added this drive to My Computer as a Network drive and then I reference the DLL's from within Visual Studio 2012 to that specific drive.

Now as you can see I have a couple of referenced DLL's from Drive X:\ which is the Mapped Network drive.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68454529/Missing%20Drive/References.JPG

This all worked fine a week ago, But now when I want to reference a new DLL from X:\ I cant find the drive
But when I go to My Computer, the drive is there and works perfectly

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68454529/Missing%20Drive/Computer.JPG

This use to work and that's how I got my other similar projects to reference from drive X.

I have already tried making the drive available offline - still not working

Any ideas of what can be wrong or how to fix this issue?

TIA

*Sorry couldn't add images here, Rep of 10 required...

Comment: `But now when I want to reference a new DLL from X:\ I cant find the drive`: what do you mean you can't find the drive? Are you going through the `Browse` screen of `Add reference`?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the second screenshot, at the bottom is a snippet of `Browse` screen to `Add reference`

Comment: Just remap your drive...

Comment: I've done that as well - same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out a different way, Instead of `Map Network drive...`

Just `Add a Network Location`:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68454529/Missing%20Drive/Solution.JPG

Now all the referenced DLL's will show the absolute path:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68454529/Missing%20Drive/DLL%20Location.JPG